# Transformer winding direction

Tags: transformer, winding, core

I am designing a center tapped transformer with 220V AC input and 12-0-12 V output. I am using a shell type core. I have a problem in choosing the direction for the turns in the centered tapped transformer. I am not sure how to choose the direction for the windings. Do I have to change after half of the turns as there is a phase shift of 180 between the two outputs?

Comment: You mean center-tapped, right? Not center-taped?

Comment: Just wind all in one direction and lead out the middle.

Comment: Consider doing a dual winding, allowing parallel connection as well as series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I am not sure how to choose the direction for turning. Do I have to
> change after half of the turns as there is a phase shift if 180
> between the two outputs?*

No, keep on winding in the same direction. If you did decide to change the turn winding direction at the centre-tap you would get net zero volts across the two extremes of the winding and, that isn't what you want.